# Как в pyqt5, при нажатии кнопки в программе с двумя окнами, закрыть только одно окно?

Tags: python, pyqt5

При открытии второго окна, нужно чтобы кнопка "Отмена" закрывала только второе окно.

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Settings import Ui_Settings

class Ui_Recovery(object):
def openWindow(self):
self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
self.ui = Ui_Settings()
self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
self.window.show()

```
def setupUi(self, Recovery):
    Recovery.setObjectName("Recovery")
    Recovery.resize(1022, 600)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Users/spank/Desktop/app.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    Recovery.setWindowIcon(icon)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Recovery)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btnStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(699, 220, 141, 41))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.btnStart.setFont(font)
    self.btnStart.setDefault(True)
    self.btnStart.setObjectName("btnStart")
    self.btnClear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btnClear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 220, 141, 41))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.btnClear.setFont(font)
    self.btnClear.setObjectName("btnClear")
    Recovery.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(Recovery)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Recovery)

def retranslateUi(self, Recovery):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Recovery.setWindowTitle(_translate("Recovery", "Восстановление"))
    self.btnStart.setText(_translate("Recovery", "Параметры"))

    self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)

    self.btnClear.setText(_translate("Recovery", "Старт"))
```

if **name** == "**main**":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Recovery = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_Recovery()
ui.setupUi(Recovery)
Recovery.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать модуль  `Settings.py`

Comment: Простите, вот он

Comment: Semyon Pankratov где ?